# Recurring Message Box VbScript

Tags: scheduled-tasks, task-manager, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I have a vbs file whose content is :

```
MsgBox "some thing here",vbOkOnly,"some other thing"
```

I have set it to run periodically using Windows Scheduler. It indeed is running periodically (which i verified by looking at the processes in task manager).
Also when i double click the vbs file it shows up.

**Problem:**

I am not getting the message box. i.e the message box doesn't appear at all.

Note: I don't know vbs.

Comment: try using this instead MsgBox "some thing here",vbSystemModal,"some other thing"

Comment: what user is it running as when scheduled?

Comment: the same user who created it

Comment: Only programs run with the setting _Run Only When User Logged In_ will be visible. You may not interrupt the logged on user with other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a scheduled task with a vbscript, you must first execute it as administrator.

You can make something like that to create a vbscript scheduled task that will run every hour for example :

```
Option Explicit
Dim FilePath,TaskName,Repeat_Task
'Run this vbscript as Admin
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
   CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute DblQuote(WScript.FullName) _
   , DblQuote(WScript.ScriptFullName) & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If

FilePath = WScript.ScriptFullName
TaskName = "MyTask"
Repeat_Task = 60      '60 minutes = 1 Hour

Call Create_Schedule_Task(Repeat_Task,TaskName,FilePath)

MsgBox "some thing here that be repeated every hour !",vbInformation,"some other thing"

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Create_Schedule_Task(Repeat_Task,TaskName,FilePath)
Dim Ws,Task,Result
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Task = "CMD /C Schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /ST 08:00 /F /RI "&_
Repeat_Task &" /DU 24:00 /TN "& TaskName &" /TR "& FilePath &""
Result = Ws.run(Task,0,True)
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Dblquote(str)
    Dblquote = chr(34) & str & chr(34)
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And if you want to check if your task is created successfully, you should open a command line and type this command :

```
schtasks /query /tn "MyTask"
```

where `MyTask` is the name that you set it before in the vbscript above.